# New harddrive doesn't sound too good, help interpretting SMART

Tags: hard-drive, smart

I installed a brand new Seagate Exos 8Tb and it's constantly producing this loud grinding noise during *any* load, and reading the reviews for the drive, some people are experiencing some noise, but not this level of it.

Should I RMA this drive?

- This is what I get after running a long S.M.A.R.T test with `smartmontools` and I wouldn't expect `Raw_Read_Error_Rate` and `Seek_Error_Rate` to have such a discrepancy between value and worst for a new [non-refurbished] drive:

  ```
  SMART Attributes Data Structure revision number: 10
  Vendor Specific SMART Attributes with Thresholds:
  ID# ATTRIBUTE_NAME          FLAG     VALUE WORST THRESH TYPE      UPDATED  WHEN_FAILED RAW_VALUE
    1 Raw_Read_Error_Rate     0x000f   081   072   044    Pre-fail  Always       -       134852481
    3 Spin_Up_Time            0x0003   091   091   000    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
    4 Start_Stop_Count        0x0032   100   100   020    Old_age   Always       -       9
    5 Reallocated_Sector_Ct   0x0033   100   100   010    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
    7 Seek_Error_Rate         0x000f   067   060   045    Pre-fail  Always       -       5527564
    9 Power_On_Hours          0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       16
   10 Spin_Retry_Count        0x0013   100   100   097    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
   12 Power_Cycle_Count       0x0032   100   100   020    Old_age   Always       -       9
  184 End-to-End_Error        0x0032   100   100   099    Old_age   Always       -       0
  187 Reported_Uncorrect      0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
  188 Command_Timeout         0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
  189 High_Fly_Writes         0x003a   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
  190 Airflow_Temperature_Cel 0x0022   056   053   040    Old_age   Always       -       44 (Min/Max 38/47)
  191 G-Sense_Error_Rate      0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       36
  192 Power-Off_Retract_Count 0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       8
  193 Load_Cycle_Count        0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       10
  194 Temperature_Celsius     0x0022   044   047   000    Old_age   Always       -       44 (0 25 0 0 0)
  195 Hardware_ECC_Recovered  0x001a   081   072   000    Old_age   Always       -       134852481
  197 Current_Pending_Sector  0x0012   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
  198 Offline_Uncorrectable   0x0010   100   100   000    Old_age   Offline      -       0
  199 UDMA_CRC_Error_Count    0x003e   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
  240 Head_Flying_Hours       0x0000   100   253   000    Old_age   Offline      -       15 (21 159 0)
  241 Total_LBAs_Written      0x0000   100   253   000    Old_age   Offline      -       132559296
  242 Total_LBAs_Read         0x0000   100   253   000    Old_age   Offline      -       2293185
  ```

Comment: Looks pretty dead. RMA. A new drive shouldn't be showing pre-fail and old age ... after only 16 hours power on ...

Comment: @DavidPostill I thought pre-fail and old-age were the type of error when the value/worst dipped below the threshold - but  they are the actual errors?

Comment: try "Clear Disk Info" , (https://www.carifred.com/cleardiskinfo/)  Fred has a nack for explaining things in simple english.

Comment: If a mechanical HDD is making a grinding sound, RMA it, as something is impeding normal operation of the motor, head, ramp, or voice coil. The only normal sounds a mechanical HDD should make are whirring _(platters spinning up to normal RPM)_, clicking _(head reaches outer platter edge and resets)_, or a fast crackling _(data being accessed)_. On a side note, for S.M.A.R.T the only way of determining whether a drive is mechanically damaged is by running a long test [`smartctl -t long /dev/<disk>`] and posting all output from the thresholds to the end of output from `smartctl -a /dev/<disk>`

Comment: _(Cont'd...) **without_ a grinding sound:** `Raw_Read_Error_Rate` usually doesn't indicate a disk hardware failure, just that a signal failure exists between a motherboard's SATA/SAS port and the HDD, with the culprit often being the SATA/SAS cable. Under the same pretext, what would indicate a hardware failure/damage to the drive would be `Offline_Uncorrectable` & `Reallocated_Sector_Ct`, combined w/ any hardware errors listed below the thresholds sections - if a drive experienced platter damage at some point, but continues to pass long tests, it's often okay to continue using w/ minimal risk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how to read it: `VALUE` is normalised to 100, lower is worse. Better than 100 is possible. If the value gets below the `THRESH` (threshold), this parameter is considered "failing".

You have a serious problem with the raw read error rate and the seek error rate (that's the "grinding" noise you hear, the drive is trying to recalibrate after a seek error or read error). The slow spin-up time also indicates there's a potential mechanical problem with the drive (too much friction can cause slower spin-up).

So while the drive is still working well enough to make a backup of whatever you put on it, that's not the state a brand-new drive should be in. Return it to the vendor and ask for an exchange/refund.